# Django loop through a list and objects in the same time

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have encountered a problem when i wanted to display some information from my list and some other information from my object. Here is what i have done so far.

I have this two class here :

```
class CoursesNames(models.Model):
    DB = "data structure"
    SF = "software enginering"
    courseChoices = (
        (DB, "data structure"),
        (SF, "software enginering"),
    )
    courses = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=courseChoices)

class Document(models.Model):

    course_name = models.ForeignKey(
    CoursesNames, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='document_courses')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(help_text="some text for now")
```

Here is my view

```
def showDocuments(request, *args, **kwargs):
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    context = {
        "documents": documents,
        "files": [], # an empty list for now 
    }

    # After writing some logic 
    context["files"].append(item)
    file_name = request.POST["course"]
    context["filename"] = file_name
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

and here is my html page: # i am stuck here !

```
{% if files %}
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         {% for file in files%}
             {% for document in documents %}
                 {% if document.course_name == filename  %}
        <div class="col-sm-4 mt-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header ">
              {{filename}}
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{document.title  }}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">this is a text where you should the best compilation of files that will definitely will help you get a st
              straight a inshallah</p>
              <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/documents/{{filename}}/{{file}}" class="btn btn-success" download>Download</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
                 {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
```

i want to show some real data instead of showing  `"here is some text"` by using the `Document` Class i have shown above so i can use  `{{document.title}}` and `{{document.description}}` but i can't find a way to do so

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here. You pass a list of all documents to the template; why can't you loop over them like you're doing with the files list?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i have done some changes please have a look at them . hopefully my changes will make it easy for you to understand my question. BTW my codes aren't showing anything now !

Comment: Well, not really. If you just want the document with a specific filename, why don't you query it specifically from the database in the view, rather than passing all documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's just a simple query as Daniel mentioned above
notice that you have a foreign key:

```
documents = Document.objects.all().filter(course_name__courses__iexact=file_name)
context["documents"] = documents
```